# In my JwtAuthenticationFilter class, I'm encountering an issue where the JWT token is not being retrieved from the header

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I'm working on my Springboot project of exam portal. there is problem i'm facing in jwt authentication it's a roled based authentication.[This is the request which I'm sending from my postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UN9x.png) . I'm not receiving Jwt token from my request.header part.[This is Where I think problem lies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEN7b.png) . You can find the complete code here `https://github.com/Apoorv3826/examserver.git`, Here is the error

```
2023-10-11T14:07:42.706+05:30  INFO 25204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-10-11T14:07:42.706+05:30  INFO 25204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-10-11T14:07:42.707+05:30  INFO 25204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-10-11T14:07:42.720+05:30  INFO 25204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter      :  Header :  null
Invalid Token 
Hibernate: 
    select
        u1_0.id,
        u1_0.email,
        u1_0.enable,
        u1_0.firstname,
        u1_0.lastname,
        u1_0.password,
        u1_0.phone,
        u1_0.profile,
        u1_0.username 
    from
        users u1_0 
    where
        u1_0.username=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        u1_0.user_id,
        u1_0.user_role_id,
        r1_0.role_id,
        r1_0.role_name 
    from
        user_role u1_0 
    left join
        roles r1_0 
            on r1_0.role_id=u1_0.role_role_id 
    where
        u1_0.user_id=?
2023-10-11T14:07:42.914+05:30 ERROR 25204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A granted authority textual representation is required] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A granted authority textual representation is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:294) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority.<init>(SimpleGrantedAuthority.java:39) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at com.pariksha.models.User.lambda$getAuthorities$0(User.java:76) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at com.pariksha.models.User.getAuthorities(User.java:76) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.createSuccessAuthentication(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:197) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.createSuccessAuthentication(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:132) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:168) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at com.pariksha.controller.AuthenticationController.authenticate(AuthenticationController.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.pariksha.controller.AuthenticationController.generateToken(AuthenticationController.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

This is the User class where i think the problem is coming

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")

public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private Long phone;
    private boolean enable = true;
    private String profile;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = this.userRoles.stream()
                .map((userRole) -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole().getRoleName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return authorities;
    }


}
```

This was the Security Configuration file

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailService userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration builder)throws Exception{
        return builder.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder (){
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.
                    csrf(csrf->csrf.disable())
                    .cors(cors->cors.disable())
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/generate-token","/user/").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .exceptionHandling(ex->ex.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                    .sessionManagement(session->session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
            http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider doDaoAuthenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }


}
```

This is My JwtUtil class for generating and validating tokens

```
@Component
public class JwtHelper {

    //requirement :
    public static final long JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY = 5 * 60 * 60;

    //    public static final long JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY =  60;
    private String secret = "afafasfafafasfasfasfafacasdasfasxASFACASDFACASDFASFASFDAFASFASDAADSCSDFADCVSGCFVADXCcadwavfsfarvf";

    //retrieve username from jwt token
    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    //retrieve expiration date from jwt token
    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    //for retrieveing any information from token we will need the secret key
    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    //check if the token has expired
    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(new Date());
    }

    //generate token for user
    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    //while creating the token -
    //1. Define  claims of the token, like Issuer, Expiration, Subject, and the ID
    //2. Sign the JWT using the HS512 algorithm and secret key.
    //3. According to JWS Compact Serialization(https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-41#section-3.1)
    //   compaction of the JWT to a URL-safe string
    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY * 1000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

Here is my JwtAuthenticationFilter Class

```java
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


        private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OncePerRequestFilter.class);
        @Autowired
        private UserDetailService userDetailService;

        @Autowired
        private JwtHelper jwtHelper;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        logger.info(" Header :  {}", requestTokenHeader);
        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer")){

            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);

            try {

                username= this.jwtHelper.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);


            }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.info("Illegal Argument while fetching the username !!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                logger.info("Given jwt token is expired !!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
                logger.info("Some changed has done in token !! Invalid Token");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


        }else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Token ");
        }

        if (username!=null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()==null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            Boolean validateToken = this.jwtHelper.validateToken(jwtToken,userDetails);
            if (validateToken)
            {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }else {
                logger.info("Validation fails !!");
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);

    }
}
```

I try almost every tutorial but nothing helps. I'm beginner on Springboot please help me with this.

Comment: So I assume that the `logger.info(" Header :  {}", requestTokenHeader);` line logs nothing? Are you sure you're sending the header?

Comment: you are aware that this login is not recommended, thats why there is no such code in spring security and you have to write everything custom. It is a security risk to hand out JWT tokens to browsers, JWTs were meant to be used between microservices within internal networks. Not out to browsers

Comment: @g00glen00b I'm doing as per my tutorials. and i also think as well as mention in post that there is some problem with header. I also added a link to screenshot of my request through Postman

Comment: @ApoorvSingh You're not showing us the right code. Your code is about obtaining + validating an incoming token, but your screenshot is about generating a token. Where's the code for that? Did you configure your security properly to not require a token for `/generate-token`?

Comment: `I'm doing as per my tutorials` and im trying to explain to you that your tutorial you are following is teaching you bad practices. All tutorials on the internet are far from good tutorials.

Comment: if you want to learn spring security i recommend reading this https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html and then read this https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html if you understand these two links you will understand most things in spring security

Comment: @g00glen00b Yes I think you're right I'm not providing the exact code file. I'm sharing the repository link of this project please guide me using this. github.com/Apoorv3826/examserver.git

Comment: Rather than sharing a link to a repository, it would be very helpful if you could filter out all the irrelevant code by yourself and share only what's necessary to reproduce the problem. I quickly checked your code and it has database-stuff, JWT-stuff, which is just too much to check for anyone who wants to answer your question. Also, Stack Overflow's rule indicate that all code necessary to solve your question must be in the question and not on a third party platform like GitHub.

Comment: @g00glen00b I'm beginner in Spring and don't exactly know which class is useful. But I updated the Question and removed previous code as per my knowledge

Answer (score -1):

from your screenshot, I assume you are doing generate-token (which mean doesn't need the Authorization token), for that you need to 'permit' the `/generate-token` endpoint to your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` or `SecurityFilterChain` Bean, depending on your spring security version

Comment: I'm very much beginner in springboot as well as web development..I'm sharing the repository link. please guide me using that. https://github.com/Apoorv3826/examserver.git